# react-router-dom - catch invalid url param

Tags: parameters, react-router, react-router-dom

The following works for localhost:3000/5 ie the user is sent to MainMap but not for localhost:3000/section/5 where they get a blank page.
I only have 4 ids (1-4) so if a user tries to type in 5 or anything other than one of the 4 ids after localhost:3000/section/ they should be sent to the MainMap component. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<MainMap />} />
    <Route path='section/:id' element={<SectionMap />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<MainMap />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would suggest creating a "guard" wrapper component to read the `id` match param and for any `id` values ***not*** in the range `[1-4]` bounce them to the other route.

```
const IdGuardWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return [1,2,3,4].some(val => val === id) // * Note
    ? <SectionMap />
    : <Navigate to={`/${id}`} replace />;
};
```

***** Note: This is *just* an example, a REGEX `/[1-4]/g.test(id)`, or similar, may also likely work.

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<MainMap />} />
  <Route
    path='section/:id'
    element={(
      <IdGuardWrapper>
        <SectionMap />
      </IdGuardWrapper>
    )}
  />
  <Route path='*' element={<MainMap />} />
</Routes>
```